# I listen to a port but still it not running the server

Tags: typescript, express, nodemon

It is working fine this morning and I just restarted my computer it is not running

I don't know how to fix this

> [nodemon] starting `ts-node src/index.ts`
>
> [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Index.ts

```js
import "dotenv/config";
import "reflect-metadata";
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import { UserResolvers } from "./UserResolvers";
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import { verify } from "jsonwebtoken";
import cors from "cors";
import { User } from "./entity/User";
import { sendRefreshToken } from "./sendRefreshToken";
import { createAccessToken, createRefreshToken } from "./auth";

(async () => {
  const app = express();
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "http://localhost:3000",
      credentials: true,
    })
  );
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.get("/", (_req, res) => res.send("hello"));
  app.post("/refresh_token", async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jid;
    if (!token) {
      return res.send({ ok: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    let payload: any = null;
    try {
      payload = verify(token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET!);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.send({ ok: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    // token is valid and
    // we can send back an access token
    const user = await User.findOne({ uid: payload.userId }.uid);

    if (!user) {
      return res.send({ ok: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    if (user.tokenVersion !== payload.tokenVersion) {
      return res.send({ ok: false, accessToken: "" });
    }

    sendRefreshToken(res, createRefreshToken(user));

    return res.send({ ok: true, accessToken: createAccessToken(user) });
  });

  await createConnection();

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [UserResolvers],
    }),
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
  });

  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false });

  app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("express server started");
  });
})();
```

tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
"include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
   "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "auth-server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
  "dependencies": {
     "apollo-server-express": "^3.10.2",
     "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
     "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
     "cors": "^2.8.5",
     "express": "^4.18.1",
     "express-session": "^1.16.1",
     "graphql": "^14.2.1",
     "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
     "pg": "^7.10.0",
     "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
     "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
     "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
     "typeorm": "0.2.16",
     "typescript": "^4.8.3"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
      "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
      "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
      "@types/express-session": "^1.15.12",
      "@types/graphql": "^14.2.0",
      "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.2",
      "@types/node": "^11.13.8",
      "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.32"
   },
  "scripts": {
      "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
      "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs"
   }
 }
```

Comment: What happens if you run without `nodemon` (so: `ts-node src/index.ts`)?

Comment: The server not starting I tried that also @robertklep

Comment: So you don't see the _"express server started"_ message? Try adding some `console.log()` statements between you code to see where exactly it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `npx ts-node ./src/index.ts`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).